# Laravel route group and middlewares

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-middleware

i am working on a laravel project with users who can have status verified (email verified).

on the other hand, users can have a subscription which is verified by a "subscriptions" middleware.

So I have several groups of routes including 2 of which the only difference is the presence of subscription or not

group 1:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ["auth:sanctum", "verified"]], function () {}
```

group 2

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ["auth:sanctum", "verified", "subscriptions"]], function () {}
```

my question is about the order laravel uses for routes in these groups. for example if the user satisfies all the middleware of the first group, does laravel test the middleware of the second?
Does a user verified have a chance to enter the second group of routes with subscription?

conversely, if the user does not have a subscription, he will not pass the subscription middleware. but I have the impression that the user is redirected by the subscription middleware which fails while laravel could find the right route in the group without this middleware (group 1)

what I would like is that it just tests for the presence of a subscription and that if it does not find one it looks for the route in group1.

Does the order of the groups in the code have an impact on the processing?

thanks.

edit:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ["auth:sanctum", "verified", ]], function () {
            Route::get("/new", function () {
               // redirect to payment
            })->name("new-payment");
    }


Route::group(['middleware' => ["auth:sanctum", "verified", "subscriptions"]], function () {
    Route::get("/new", function () {
        return view("bourse-new");
    })->name("new-abo");
```

it is the same route but with a different behavior depending on the presence or not of a subscription
When subscriptions middleware fails, it's redirect to "home", but i want laravel to use the first route

Comment: Do the actual routes differ? Can you priovide examples? You might be able to just nest your groups/middleware.

Comment: @Peppermintology thanks for your interest.

I would like, if the user has a subscription that he can create a new item, and if not that he is redirected to a payment.

Comment: So you are saying that even the ```subscriptions```  middleware is returning ```false``` routes inside the group is accessiable ?

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai, 
the routes inside the group do not become accessible, but as "subscription" fails, it redirects to "home" and I would simply like it to use the route of the 1st group, the one without this middleware

Comment: No You cannot add same URI to different route

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai ok thanks, but I want a different behavior depending on the presence or not of a subscription

Comment: last route with the uri will be executed

Comment: btw, groups are just conceptual, all routes are registered individually and in order ... groups are just for cascading configuration ... it is no different then registering them individually outside of groups, so the order they are registered in is important for how the router will match the route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @NoobDev.

I took over his solution by integrating the subscription tests into middleware

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ["auth:sanctum", "verified"]], function () {
    Route::get("/new", function () {
        return view("bourse-new");
    })->middleware("subscriptions")->name("bourse-new");
});
```

and the subscriptions middleware:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
    if( //logic tests) {
         return $next($request);
     }
     return redirect('/checkout'); //redirect to payment
}
```

this solution is almost perfect, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

> my question is about the order laravel uses for routes in these
> groups. for example if the user satisfies all the middleware of the
> first group, does laravel test the middleware of the second?

If you hit a route included in the first group laravel won't check the other one.

> Does a
> user verified have a chance to enter the second group of routes with
> subscription?

If he hasn't the subscription he cannot

> Does the order of the groups in the code have an impact on the processing?

Yes, if you used the same uri the last one will override the previous one

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ["auth:sanctum", "verified", ]], function () {
            Route::get("/new", function () {
               // redirect to payment
            })->name("new-payment");
    }


Route::group(['middleware' => ["auth:sanctum", "verified", "subscriptions"]], function () {
    Route::get("/new", function () {
        return view("bourse-new");
    })->name("new-abo");
```

Try php artisan route:list, the second group is probably overriding the first

> ok thanks, but I want a different behavior depending on the presence
> or not of a subscription

In User Model:

```
public function hasSubscribed()
{
    //do your logic to check if has subscription
}
```

You could use the first group and check if the Auth::user() has subscribed. something like this:

```
if (auth()->user()->hasSubscribed()) { 
    return view()
} 
    
//or ...
```

Comment: you're right, with route: list, only the second route appears.

Comment: brilliant your solution, so obvious that I wonder why I did not think of it.

Comment: Nothing brilliant! By the way always glad to help

Answer (score 0):

In `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticatesRequests::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequestsWithRedis::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];
```

Docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#sorting-middleware